# Polynomials Reference Request

Tags: polynomials, reference-request

I am searching for bibliographical references to polynomials that are a product of sums where each term of the product has one more summand variable than the previous one, i.e. something like $P(x_1,\dots,x_n) = x_1(x_1+x_2)(x_1+x_2+x_3)\dots(x_1+\dots+x_n)$. Do these have a certain name, special properties, or been studied at all in the maths literature?

Comment: I doubt that there is a special name for them, or that they are of special interest. Why do you think so? Which properties do they have?

Comment: @MariusS.L. The polynomials of these type are of interest in Combinatorics. Essentially the encode permutation with special properties given by the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You can call it the **rising factorial of the sequence $\{x_n\},$** and denote it by $\left (x_k\right )^{\overline{n}}$ notice that if $x_i=1$ then you recover the factorial $n!,$ if $x_n = x+n-1$ you recover the normal rising factorial $x^{\overline{n}}.$ If $x_i = q^{i-1},$ you recover the $[n]_q!$ $q-$factorial.
 People study these objects but not in full generalized form because is hard to say anything about them, they are too general! The only think that I can think you can say is that
$$(x_k)^{\overline{n}}=\sum _{\substack{(a_1,\cdots ,a_n)\\1\leq a_j\leq j}}\prod _{i=1}^nx_{a_i}.$$ which is saying not much.
Probably you will enjoy this reference: [Generalized j-Factorial Functions, Polynomials, and Applications](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL13/Schmidt/multifact.html) by Maxie Schmidt.